# Follow up question on linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

So I asked a question recently:

[Finding the matrix of this linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91324/finding-the-matrix-of-this-linear-transformation)

and I'm wondering something else.

> $T : V \to V$ is a linear transformation. There is a vector $v \in V$ such that $T^n(v) = 0$. We're also told that the vectors $T^{n-1}(v), T^{n-2}(v), \ldots, T(v), v$ form a basis for $V$.

Let's also add that $T^{n-1}(v) \neq 0$

What if we're not told what the basis is? How do you find a basis for the transformation, or at least prove that it is a basis?

In general, a set of vectors is a basis for a space if the vectors are linearly independent and they span the space. How can we show that if we're not given what the actual vectors are?

Edit: My question boils down to: How do I show that those vectors form a basis for V, if we don't even know what V is?

Comment: a) What does "=/=" stand for? b) There is no such thing as a basis for a transformation. A basis is a basis for a vector space. c) Your question is extremely general. In different scenarios, one might use all sorts of methods to find a basis or prove that a given set is a basis. Do you have anything more specific in mind?

Comment: The fact that $T^{n-1}(v)\neq 0$ follows from "$T^{n-1}(v)$, $T^{n-2}(v),\ldots,T(v),v$ form a basis for $V$". No basis can include the zero basis.

Comment: Above, for "zero basis", read "zero vector".

Comment: I follow that. I guess my question can be revised to "How do I show that those vectors are indeed a basis for V?"

Comment: @JohnDoe: In this generality, **you cannot**. There is not enough information to guarantee it.

Comment: @joriki: Oops; quite so. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "basis for the transformation". In this context, *Vector spaces* have bases, not linear transformations.

What you are looking at is the beginning of the systematic study that leads to the [Rational Canonical Form of a transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_canonical_form).

Though it takes quite a bit of doing, one can prove that for any finite dimensional vector space $V$, and any linear transformation $T$, there exist vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$, and positive integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ such that:

1. $v_i$, $T(v_i)$, $T^2(v_i),\ldots,T^{n_i-1}(v_i)$ are linearly independent for each $i$.
2. $T^{n_i}(v_i)$ is a linear combination of $v_i,T(v_i),\ldots,T^{n_i-1}(v_i)$ for each $i$.
3. $v_1,\ldots,T^{n_1-1}(v_1),v_2,\ldots,T^{n_2-1}(v_2),\ldots,T^{n_k-1}(v_k)$ is a basis for $V$.

These form "nice" bases when the matrix is not diagonalizable and when there is no [Jordan canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_canonical_form) available. (There are a few other properties that go into the rational canonical form besides the 3 above).

Comment: I asked my teacher today, and she showed an inductive argument that shows that the last two vectors $T^{n-1}(v), T^{n-2}(v)$ are linearly independent, and you can generalize it to show that all the vectors are linearly independent. Since we have n lin. indep. vectors in n-dimensions, they must form a basis, and the argument was done. Is that what you were referring to w.r.t. the work to prove 1,2,3?

Comment: @John: I don't know what it was your teacher showed you, but there were more assumptions than simply the fact that you had a linear transformation; it is *not* the case that for every linear transformation you can find a v for which what you claim holds, so there were extra assumptions at play.